# How to make an image as large as possible in a CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive

I need to display an image as large as possible in my layout. The image can be of any size and/or ratio, and it must work with landscape or portrait device orientation (responsive).

#### Actual CSS layout description

My layout is a simple CSS grid with:

- a header on the top,
- the main content where the image must fit (with a commands area on the bottom),
- and a nav bar on the bottom.

The actual main area is a `display:flex`, in order to display some photo commands on the bottom, and the real `img` tag is wrapped into a `div.photo-frame` element, in order to display a large white border around the image.

*Note*: This border could have been rendered by a CSS `border` property on the image, but I would like to keep it as a `<div>`, in case if extra elements should be added into the white frame, below the image (e.g.: image caption, links...).

#### What I tried

I tried many things, but the `div.photo-frame` element causes problems because ~ it doesn't know the size of the image ~ (#forgivethenoob).

#### What I need

It would be really great if someone could adapt the one-file code I give just below to a working version.

I guess it is a trivial task for a CSS expert; sorry for duplicate.

#### Single file code (html+css)

Here is a full example (as minimal as possible, only the cat image is missing):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            margin: 0;

            color: #aaa;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .layout {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows:
                4rem
                auto
                4rem;
            grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "nav";

            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        header {
            grid-area: header;
            background-color: #330;
        }

        main {
            grid-area: main;
            background-color: #033;
        }

        nav {
            grid-area: nav;
            background-color: #303;
        }

        #page-1 {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;

            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #page-1 .photo-zone {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;

            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        /* I prefer to use this class (.photo-frame) instead of a simple border property on the image,
         * because some stuff might be added inside the white frame, below the image: */
        #page-1 .photo-zone .photo-frame {
            display: flex;

            padding: 4px;

            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 0.2rem;
        }

        #page-1 .photo-commands {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }

        #cat {
            width: 200px; /* This needs to be removed in order to answer the question */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layout">
        <header>Header (fixed height)</header>
        <main>
            <div id="page-1">
                <div class="photo-zone">
                    <div class="photo-frame">
                        <img id="cat" src="cat.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="photo-commands">
                    Photo commands
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="page-2" style="display:none"></div>
            <div id="page-3" style="display:none"></div>
        </main>
        <nav>Nav bar (fixed height)</nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Here is a rendering of the above code (fixed size image: width=200px)

[image: Code rendering]

#### Here is what I would like in a landscape orientation

[image: Landscape example]

#### Here is what I would like in a portrait orientation

[image: Portrait example]